# How to get a list of all token holders using ethers.js + metamask

Tags: web3js, metamask, ethers.js

Is there any way, using ethers.js and metamask, to build an array of all current token holders? I would need this to my project which I'm currently working at.

I know I can download the entire blockchain but are there simplier ways to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Using the Covalent API is a free way to get token holders without having to create a database of transaction history.

https://www.covalenthq.com/docs/api/#/0/Get%20token%20holders%20as%20of%20any%20block%20height/USD/1

Using ethers.js you can also use the EtherscanProvider to access their API and get token holder list.
https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/api-providers/

https://docs.etherscan.io/api-endpoints/tokens#get-token-holder-list-by-contract-address